# django annotate/count two columns at the same time

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-models

I have a table called relationships. I want to return the top 10 users with the most relationships. Think of something like the most popular users list.

I've seen examples on returning the top occurrences in one column, but both? Here's a sample of the table:

```
user_a | user_b
     1 |      2
     2 |      5
     3 |      4
     4 |      5
     1 |      4
     2 |      6
     1 |      5
```

Here's an example of the model:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):
    user_a = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_a')
    user_b = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_b')
```

How would I create such a query set in django?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a raw query like this:

```
select user, count(*)
from (
select user_a as user
from table
union all
select user_b as user
from table )
group by user
order by count(*) desc
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. I tried to run this directly on the database and got the following error:
ERROR:  subquery in FROM must have an alias

I edited the query so the 7th line looks like this:
"from userprofile_relationship ) as foo"

And then it just returns a number.